# Redmi 9 Prime hard bricked

Tags: adb, custom-roms, twrp, fastboot, unbricking

I will explain every step I took till this point to maybe help explain the situation

I ran into multiple problems from today's evening

The first was the drivers i guess, I tried to unlock the phone (Redmi 9 Prime) after waiting more than sufficient time in the official tool. But the official tool won't recognize my phone so I tried installing many drivers, tried many cables, different ports, etc.
Nothing seemed to work.

I came across an unofficial tool called XiaoMiToolV2. This recognized my phone and unlocked my phone successfully.

After that I tried to install TWRP on my phone.
The commands I used were:

```
fastboot flash recovery twrp.img
fastboot flash vbmeta vbmeta.img
```

Unfortunately I messed up in the next command, instead of trying to boot into the TWRP image, I accidentally flashed it to the boot partition

```
fastboot flash boot twrp.img
```

I was suppposed to delete the flash word from the line..
I pressed enter before I realized and it was done..
I tried the originally intended command anyway:

```
fastboot boot twrp.img
```

But it was too late i guess, the phone was bricked and I could not access anything other than the Fastboot mode itself.
Next to fix that I tried using the same XiaoMiToolV2 which had an option called Fix Bootloop or something along that line
I pressed that and it seemed to download the latest stock ROM and flash it with fastboot

The process seemed to be successful but the bootloop was still there.

So I looked into it and downloaded the MIUI 12.5 Global Fastboot ROM along with MiFlash tool

This ended up being unsuccessful as the it kept returning "Flash preloader error"

I looked at the "flash_all.bat" file and tried executing the command that flashes the preloader manually using fastboot. It worked, so I did the same thing for the subsequent commands in order. Everything was successful and I was hopeful ( I am suspecting the firmware was not compatible with my phone but it did say "lancelot" idk why then and forcing to be flashed bricked my phone? )

Then I finally did `fastboot reboot` after all the operations got over and that's it
Till that point the phone was atleast turning on and booting to Fastboot mode, then it just didn't respond to anything completely powered down

I tried charging the phone for 30 minutes, still no response.
After a bit of research I am now skeptical that the device may be completely bricked.. But I haven't done anything outside the things I mentioned here..

Comment: https://forum.xda-developers.com/t/hardbricked-redmi-9-mt6769.4302829/post-85441123

Comment: In the post which says it's solved following a tutorial, the tutorial link is broken..
anyway update, I used the SP Flash tool along with stock firmware and got somewhere it showed the Redmi logo but powered down once again and now it's not getting recognized by SP Flash tool either..

Comment: preloader mode works best without battery

Comment: Ah yes.. that would be ideal but it's a non-removal battery. Almost all modern phones are right?
Preloader mode did get detected in the first try, SP Flash tool was flashing, the phone booted to "Redmi" boot screen and then the flashing got interrupted in the middle. Then it never registered as Mediatek COM port again just Unknown device
It didn't finish the flashing so it's not booting to anything either..

Comment: flashing preloader is risky and almost never necessary. on weak usb connection it might have corrupted preloader. disconnect battery, search for kcol0 test point and short it to ground (do not solder it)